# How to set the unique integer id in java for each request in the clustered environment?

Tags: java, unique-key, sequence-generators

I want to set the unique integer id in each request, that we will send to other system. This id should start from 1 and should increment until 2147483647. Once it reached 2147483647, it should again start from 1.

We have a clustered environment and request could come from any servers. So from whichever server the request may come from, the unique id should always get the latest value set and should increment it by 1 and need to set the new value in the request.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Yu haven't tols us much about your architecture. But if you use a relational database, define a sequence in the database, and use it to generate IDs.

Comment: This looks like bad design. You need to sync the ID generation between your servers/clients. This cause a performance problem. Why you want do this?

Comment: Yes, we do have relational database. But is there any other way, just to keep it as a objects in java, rather than storing it in DB.

Comment: Use a UUID instead.

Comment: @SivapandianJayakumar if you went to keep this design, you can't possibly know what the other servers have already sent, so you need some way of knowing, and a central place responsible to handle the counter and incrementing it is the easiest way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of keeping a uniqueID in the request and increasing the complexity. I would rather suggest of handling creation of uniqueId logic in your Controller endpoint. In that way your request need not worry about the uniqueID and can function independently as all request are supposed to be.